# Instantiate class with type parameters with the type of a variable in Scala

Tags: scala, type-parameter

I’ve got the following types

```
class Translator[To <: Language] { ... }
abstract class Language
object English extends Language
object German extends Language
```

Is there a way to instantiate `Translator` from a `val` that is either of type `English` or `German`?

I’m looking for something like the following (which doesn’t work):

```
val lang = if (someCondition) English else German
val translator = new Translator[classOf[lang]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the language as type argument in Translator constructor:

```
class Translator[To <: Language](lang:To) {...}
abstract class Language
object English extends Language
object German extends Language

new Translator(German)
res7: Translator[German.type] = Translator@8beab46

// using class instead of object:
class Italian extends Language
new Translator(new Italian)
res9: Translator[Italian] = Translator@6bc22f58
```

Comment: I prefer this answer since it still uses generic types.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that neither `English` or `German` are classes. Are you sure that you need genericity here? Maybe composition is sufficient. A possible solution is:

```
val lang = Translator(if (someCondition) English else German)
```

with the following classes and objects:

```
case class Translator(l: Language)
trait Language
object English extends Language
object German extends Language
```

But it's a quite different design than the one you expected...

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Your second point was a mistake in my code. I fixed it. I just removed too much of the boilerplate to clarify my issue. I am not sure what the problem is with `English` and `German` not being classes.

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer accordingly. But the point is: is there a good reason to use generic types here ?

Comment: You can’t know why I’m actually using generic types here. In my code every language has its own `apply` method, which itself has a generic type. This type defines a enumeration of Terms that can be translated by the `Translator`. So actually the `Translator` has a second type parameter, that applies to its `apply` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just instantiate `Translator` with the type of `German` or `English` like this:

```
new Translator[German.type]
```

edit:

or from a `val`

```
val x = German
new Translator[x.type]
```

Comment: The answer is correct but doesn’t answer my question (`val`).